# Deadlock/hard freezing on UITextField/UITextView/UISearchBar becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm experiencing intermittent hard freezing of multiple apps on UITextFields, UITextViews and UISearchBars becomingFirstResponder. The freeze happens before the keyboard comes onto the screen. The app does eventually seem to recover, but takes a very long time. Most users will loose patience before this happens however.

The common factor between the apps seems to be registering for UIKeyboardWillShowNotifications, but a trivial amount of work is done in the selectors registered for this notification.

Is anyone else seeing this and/or found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem. In my case, it wan only iPad and stuck on [textView becomeFirstResponder] for about 3 minutes. I delete the app and downloaded my app from app store and confirmed the live version does not have the issue. I went back to Xcode and run after restoring all changes I made to fix the bug. Everything works fine now.

Comment: For me it is happening only on iPad too.
What's interesting is that the bug doesn't appear if I try to Profile my app with Time Profiler :) 
Thanks man, you saved me a lot of time!